# Running Vertica in docker in AWS EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, vertica

I'm trying so use vertica - colemantw/vertica (https://hub.docker.com/r/colemantw/vertica) image in docker in AWS EC2 instance.
EC2 type is m4.4xlarge.

Docker is installed (hello-world is working fine) but I see below output when running container:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ sudo docker run -p 5433:5433 colemantw/vertica
Info: no password specified, using none
Unable to read database catalogs - cannot start database.
Database docker did not start successfully
Shutting Down
Info: no password specified, using none
Database docker is not currently running
```

Any idea what can be a reason? 
Locally it is working fine, vertica is running

Comment: First off - no need to use `sudo`; secondly, ensure your Docker daemon is already running.

Comment: docker is running, and i need to use sudo in ec2

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to comment on with regards to the `colemantw/vertica` container. But Vertica does have an official container now. You may want to try out `vertica/vertica-ce`